# how to pass data from api to gojs TreeModel

Tags: javascript, arrays, gojs

I am not bale to display links using GOJS and TreeModel. I am able to create nodes but not links.

I am thinking this is related to the fact GOJS uses a data array as opposed to json.

```
    var $ = go.GraphObject.make;
    var myDiagram =
        $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",
            {
                "undoManager.isEnabled": true, // enable Ctrl-Z to undo and Ctrl-Y to redo
                layout: $(go.TreeLayout, // specify a Diagram.layout that arranges trees
                    { angle: 90, layerSpacing: 35 })
            });

    // the template we defined earlier
    myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
        $(go.Node, "Horizontal",
            { background: "#44CCFF" },
            $(go.Picture,
                { margin: 10, width: 50, height: 50, background: "red" },
                new go.Binding("source")),
            $(go.TextBlock, "Default Text",
                { margin: 12, stroke: "white", font: "bold 16px sans-serif" },
                new go.Binding("text", "name"))
        );

    var model = $(go.TreeModel);
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/api/Employees/", false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    var nodeArray = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    //model = nodeArray;
        myDiagram.model.nodeDataArray = nodeArray;
    //myDiagram.model = model;
```

Comment: myDiagram.linkTemplate =
            $(go.Link,
                { routing: go.Link.Orthogonal, corner: 5 },
                $(go.Shape, { strokeWidth: 3, stroke: "#555" })); // the link shape

Comment: it does not work with linkTemplate added

Comment: My json:       [{ "key": "U000000", "parent": null, "name": "Greg A Lowe", "title": "MD" },
            { "key": "U111111", "parent": "U000000", "name": "Roman Ha", "title": "MD" },
            { "key": "U222222", "parent": "U111111", "name": "Jason Wu", "title": "MD" },
            { "key": "U333333", "parent": "U222222", "name": "George Smith", "title": "MD" }]

Answer (score 0):

If you check the console window, you will see this error message:

```
Error: ParentKey value for node data [object Object] is not a number or a string: null
```

That is because you set:

```
"parent": null
```

in one of your node data objects.  I suggest that you remove that property.

I also suggest that you use the `go-debug.js` library instead of the `go.js` library, because the Debug version of the library will detect and warn you about more problems than the regular version of the library.